# How does s_client turn ip6-localhost into 127.0.0.1?

Tags: openssl, ipv6, ipv4

When I use `openssl s_client` and ask it to connect to `ip6-localhost` it actually connects to `127.0.0.1` instead of `::1`.

This is what I see on both Ubuntu and Debian:

```
$ strace -e connect openssl s_client -connect ip6-localhost:443
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_FILE, path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
connect(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(443), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = 0
```

I don't see anything in `/etc/hosts` which could explain the behavior:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       dell

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

How does `s_client` reach the conclusion that the IP address of `ip6-localhost` is `127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Maybe it's working around [the bug that removed the localhost entry](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/netbase/+bug/301430)?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I don't see the connection.